# How to Iterate object array [Gson deserialize]?

Tags: java, json, loops, gson

```
[{bulkNo=91200256, cardType=CDMA_PP, denomination=300, endSerial=6048233, epfId=2254, nextSerialValue=6048226, startSerial=6048225}, {bulkNo=12050021, cardType=CDMA_PP, denomination=200, endSerial=6057151, epfId=2254, nextSerialValue=6057131, startSerial=6057131}, {bulkNo=12100005, cardType=CDMA_PP, denomination=100, endSerial=6003841, epfId=2254, nextSerialValue=6003842, startSerial=6003841}]
```

above shows my Gson array when i debug.need to iterate it and create objects from that

here shows my code

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<SerialDetails> serialDetails =new ArrayList<SerialDetails>();  
        serialDetails = gson.fromJson(sendJsonDataList, ArrayList.class);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < serialDetails.size() ; i++){
            SerialDetails item = (SerialDetails) serialDetails.get(i);//ERROR COMES IN HERE
            System.out.println(item);
        }
```

and here shows my error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to mainService.SerialDetails
    at mainService.Sales.sendJsonDataList(Sales.java:677)
    at mainService.TSR_WEB_SERVICE.sendJsonDataList(TSR_WEB_SERVICE.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to sort-out this issue.my bean class correctly created with getters and setters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your final solution should be working fine as you commented, you could also use a `List` object as in your first approach. Because, by the way, in your final solution you're creating a `List` that you're not using!

You just need to use a `TypeToken`, since `List.class` doesn't work as you may expect and you cannot do `List<SerialDetails>.class`...

So, you need something like:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SerialDetails>>() {}.getType();
List<SerialDetails> serialDetails = new Gson().fromJson(sendJsonDataList, listType);
//Now you can iterate over your List...
```

Answer (score 1):

i used with ArrayList.Class but its working Fine in My Application.

Comment: Dear Hareesh..I used this in my Android + KSOAP/Axis2 Web service application.its not worked perfectly. so i changed like that and now its worked fine

Answer (score 0):

issue corrected 
i'm mistakenly used object arraylist instead for objectarray

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<SerialDetails> serialDetails =new ArrayList<SerialDetails>();  
        SerialDetails[] serialDetailsRecords = gson.fromJson(sendJsonDataList, SerialDetails[].class);
        for (SerialDetails item: serialDetailsRecords) {
             item.toString();
        }
```

now its works perfect

thanks for all

Comment: Please, since you solved, mark your question as answer and don't forget to check @MikO advice.